# how to merge listactivity and actionbaractivity?

Tags: android

I want to make button share at right corner
 So i used [this](https://github.com/ludovicroland/smartShareActionProvider-android). 
But my project has used extent ListActivity,so how to merge ActionBarActivity and ListActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ListActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` and find ListView 
e.g:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Now for your activity:

```
public class MyOldListActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

use ListFragment instead of ListActivity

Comment: But this will be more complicated if i use fragment .cry

Comment: No it's not that complicated and it's better by the way.

Comment: just use Custom Viewgroups :3

Comment: Iwill use solution from adeel ahmad because he profide example

Comment: @suryati do accept the answer as well if it solves your problem

Comment: But i used simple adapter ahmed. ..this will complicated too